# Function revert with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, revert

I have a little question. Is there any possible to revert function with jquery?
I have some click function with actions in the middle of it. Can i revert this elements to condition before click? Thx 4 help.

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_02').click(function(){
    $('#recipe_panel').css('opacity','1');
    $('.default_clock, .info_top_panel .random_title, .bottom_panel_button_06').css('display','none');
    $('.bottom_main_panel_button').css('background','url("img/ap_bottom_panel_button_white.png") center bottom no-repeat')
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.arrow_up, .arrow_down').fadeIn(300);
    },500);
    $('.main_content, .oven_panel').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to revert a bucnch of DOM manipulations/animations using jQuery. You'll have to write 2 functions which mirror each other and write the code associated:

```
function action(){
    $('#recipe_panel').css('opacity','1');
    $('.default_clock, .info_top_panel .random_title, .bottom_panel_button_06').css('display','none');
    $('.bottom_main_panel_button').css('background','url("img/ap_bottom_panel_button_white.png") center bottom no-repeat')
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.arrow_up, .arrow_down').fadeIn(300);
    },500);
    $('.main_content, .oven_panel').fadeOut(200);    
}

function revert(){
    $('#recipe_panel').css('opacity','0');
    $('.default_clock, .info_top_panel .random_title, .bottom_panel_button_06').css('display','block');
    $('.bottom_main_panel_button').css('background','')
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.arrow_up, .arrow_down').fadeOut(300);
    },500);
    $('.main_content, .oven_panel').fadeIn(200);    
}

$('.bottom_panel_button_02').click(action);
$('.someOtherButton').click(revert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using [custom attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bottom_panel_button_02').attr("clicked", "false");

    $('.bottom_panel_button_02').click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");

        if (clicked == "false") {
            // do your click function

            $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
        } else {
            // do your revert function

            $(this).attr("clicked", "false");
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could have a global variable / hidden input element that is set, instead of using attributes.  You could also .addClass and .removeClass depending on the clicked state of the element and have your states in these CSS classes.

Comment: yeah, i could do this but it's overwrite back all of the elements, i don't wanna do it that way...

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski in that case there is no straight "revert" function for the DOM you'd have to do this yourself. Another way you could achieve this is duplicating all "clickable" elements in your DOM in a hidden div with some ID and write your own revert which will just fetch the original element from the div and replace the clicked element with that copy, this will add a pretty hefty overhead to downloading your page though.

Comment: this is some kind of idea, but i thing the better way could be turn this all action away to natural condition - thx for interest